# Mikrotik на 2 провайдера

Tags: сеть, администрирование, mikrotik

Имеется маршрутизатор MikroTik-RB2011iL который 3-й день пытаюсь настроить на работу с 2-мя провайдерами. Уже всю голову сломал, не могу понять что я делаю не так.
Вводные данные следующие:
Провайдер 1:
IP: 10.1.0.40
GW: 10.1.0.1

Провайдер 2:
IP: 92.205.228.178 (белый IP)
GW: 92.205.228.177

Lan:
10.1.10.0/24

Необходимо пускать весь трафик из LAN через провайдера 1. В случае отказа провайдера 1 переключать на провайдера 2. В тоже время провайдер 2 тоже должен быть доступен т.к. через белый IP провайдера 2 будут пробросы портов в LAN. Вроде все просто. Маркируем трафик провайдеров и LAN и пускаем все по соответствующим маршрутам. Из сети провайдера 1 ко мне доступ есть. Из LAN доступ есть только через 1-го провайдера. Не могу получить доступ через провайдера 2. Не пингуется IP и все тут. Конфигурацию маршрутизатора прилагаю. Может кто глянет и подскажет что я делаю не так.

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/kjyAaomXdRTvAw

Answer (score 0):

Добавь правило `/ip firewall nat add action=masquerade chain=srcnat`

Answer (score -1):

ошибка в этой строке:

```
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=!10.1.10.0/24 out-interface=eth7_ISP2 src-address=10.1.10.0/24
```

ещё. всю маркировку я бы делал в prerouting. и соединений и роутинга.
можно ещё и в output, но проще (и правильней) решить это через /route rule

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]